# Linux Redhat 6.0 booting freezed at “starting RHM Managed Xen Domains”

Tags: xen, boot

1. One of our Linux redhat 6.0, 64 bit machines freezes **after the step of

"starting RHM Managed Xen Domains"** during booting. It has been staying there

for days without successful booting. Rebooting with two other kernels results in

the same freezing status. Google doesn't seem to offer any solution. May I know

if any guru has any solution? Thanks!!

2. The image of the freezing booting step is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B84zOE6DopPlSHdkSjV6UFo4ZTQ/view?usp=sharing) (sorry I am new here, so I cannot attach the image directly)

Comment: Redhat 6.0 or RHEL?

Comment: It says RedHat enterprise 6.0, so I am assuming it is RHEL 6.0?

Comment: Today the boot stops at the "readahead-collector: finished", right after the “starting RHM Managed Xen Domains”.   I saw there was a post (   http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/red-hat-31/boot-up-gets-stuck-at-readahead-collector-finished-900233/  ) but don't quite understand what does this mean "Try starting in single-user mode, and look in the /etc/rcX.d/ (where X is the troublesome runlevel) directory. See what is alphabetically after the atd startup script. Remove that, and see if it fixes the problem. "  : (